# Unity dash seems fine but some apps lack a menu

Tags: unity, appmenu

Unity dash seems fine but some apps lack a menu.

Chrome has a full and working menu but Libre Office and GIMP have no menu at all.

**Version: 16.04 LTS; 64 bit**

Comment: You haven't mentioned your OS/release, which is rather helpful.  Unity was default for example in 16.04, but `ubuntu-unity-desktop` needs to be added on later releases and it could be you didn't add all requirements...

Comment: I've added the OS/release. FYI I have not seen this problem (that I recall) on this PC and I've had it a long old while.

Comment: I suspect it's how developed; GIMP still relies on GTK2 (has yet to be ported to GTK3), where as your desktop is using GTK3 (ie. older libraries don't know about dash & GTK3 features), and LibreOffice is java based so I guess doesn't call GTK3 but sorry that is pure guess (I don't know what APIs java would call so I can only guess on that one).